# REST and redirecting the response

Tags: rest, http-request, http-response

I'm developing a RESTful service.  Here is a map of the current feature set:

```
POST /api/document/file.jpg    (creates the resource)
GET /api/document/file.jpg     (retrieves the resource)
DELETE /api/document/file.jpg  (removes the resource)
```

So far, it does everything you might expect.  I have a particular use case where I need to set up the browser to send a POST request using the multipart/form-data encoding for the document upload but when it is completed I want to redirect them back to the form.  I know how to do a redirect, but I'm not certain about how the client and server should negotiate this behavior.  Two approaches I'm considering:

1. On the server check for the `multipart/form-data` encoding and, if present, redirect to the referrer when the request is complete.
2. Add a service URI of `/api/document/file.jpg/redirect` to redirect to the referrer when the request is complete.

I looked into setting an X header (X-myapp-redirect) but you can't tell the browser which headers to use like this.  I manage the code for both the client and the server side so I'm flexible on solutions here.  Is there a best practice to follow here?

Comment: First - the create should probably be a PUT, not poas POST.  Also not clear on what the POST is doing with its multipart upload, can you elaborate? Any why go back to the form anyways - what is the purpose of that?

Comment: The POST request is sending a document from client using a form upload.  I agree about PUT, but the jury is somewhat out on browser support there.  The use case is returning to the form with a flash message with a response status.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a pretty classic case of [POST/Redirect/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), and is sort of the expected behavior for web applications. I'd probably make that the default.

If you're not a fan of that approach for whatever reason, consider using AJAX (which means you can use the `PUT` approach mentioned by @sdg in a comment) with a standard 201 and the response body can contain the flash message to be displayed. The AJAX can do what you need it to do with the flash message, at that point.